# We're open / We're closed

Tags: php, time

```
<?php 

$time = date('Hi');

if ($time > 0030) {
    echo "closed";
} elseif ($time >= 0800) {
    echo "open";
}
?>
```

This is the code i'm using for a client's website. In short it's a code that'll show if the client's business is open or not.

My client's working hours are between 8am to 12:30am.

I was wondering if there's an easier way of doing this or am I doing this right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Date Open and Close Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460511/php-date-open-and-close-script)

Comment: That code is broken - consider inputs of '0005' which if not > '0030' nor greater than '0800'; Also, consider a value of '0930' which is greater than '0030' so would report closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); # set timezone according to your requirement
$now = new DateTime();
$start = new DateTime('today 08:00:00');
$end = new DateTime('tomorrow  00:30:00');
if ($start <= $now && $now < $end) {
    echo "open";
}
else{
    echo "close";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Glavić..but in my side it will return `open`

Comment: @Glavić ..`DateTime('today 00:15:00');` mean last night and store opening time is morning 8am

Comment: Every day at 00:15:00 store is opened. This is how I understand OP.