# Shop is open or not using php

Tags: javascript, php

i am a very beginner at PHP , and i am currently working on Shop is open or close module.
   I am troubling in one functionality while converting into timestamp.
    below is the code , please help me to solve this functionality.

I am taking three array ,1st is for week day , 2nd is for first_half and 3rd is for second_half.
    the problem is that i am not able to find out the timestamp for 2nd array and 3rd array.
    so i am not able to do the comparison between the timestamp.
    please help me this out.

```
    function open_close($week_day,$first_half,$second_half)
    {
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

            foreach ($first_half as $first_key) {


                $first=date('d-m-Y h:m:s A').$first_key;//concatenating the first array element to date for finding the timestamp
                echo $first_half_str=strtotime($first);echo"<br>"; 

                /*$second=date('d-m-Y h:m:s A').$second_half;
                echo $second_half=strtotime($second);echo "<br>";*/////concatenating the second array element to date for finding the timestamp but don't know how to add second element in this foreach loop.

                $final=date('d-m-Y h:m:s A');
                echo $final_timestamp=strtotime($final);echo"<br>";

                if($first_half_str < $final_timestamp)//troubling for comparison  cause not having any prior data to compare.
                {
                    echo "open";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "close";
                }
            }           
    }
$week_day=array('Monday','Tuesday','Thursday','Wednesday','Friday');//week array
    $first_half=array ('09:00:00 AM','10:00:00 AM','11:00:00 AM','12:00:00 AM','01:00:00 PM');//first half array
    $second_half=array ('03:00:00 PM','04:00:00 PM','05:00:00 PM','06:00:00 PM','07:00:00 PM');//second half array

    open_close($week_day,$first_half,$second_half);
 ?>
```

give me guide for this module.
    it will very helpfull for me for adding a new knowledge in my pocket. 
I am stick on this trouble , kindly give me guide to solve this problem.
there are alot articles related to it , but i want to do it on my own.

Comment: I'll just give you a tip: don't use strings to work with dates. Cast to string when you finally *display* dates to user but make all your internal variables be actual dates (either good old Unix timestamps or DateTime objects).

Comment: can you give me some example , so i can understand properly. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `date('d-m-Y h:m:s A').$first_key` ...  this will give you something like: "21-06-2016 01:56:12 PM 09:00:00 AM" (You're appending `$first_key` to a complete date-string) .. not really a valid date string

Comment: any suggestions on this?? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Sure... Google ;-) This is a common programming test so there are multiple solutions out there..  here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460511/php-date-open-and-close-script